# TFS new solution get sucked into old projects source site

Tags: tfs

I have a new server location on TFS for a new solution.  As I added existing projects to new solution the server binding from an existing project was used to store source.  This project should have it's code in ShowUBForm not in Utilities.  Utilities is where my DAL code lives.

How to I disconnect in TFS the ServerBinding to "$/Utilities/ShowUBForm" to What I want "$/ShowUBForm/ShowUBForm/